# How do you properly use multiple group_concats on multiple subqueries within one query without distinct?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, aggregate-functions, group-concat

I have a rather monstrous query where I'm pulling information for either a particular user, or several users.  I need to get multiple sets of normalized attributes for this user reaching out through link tables for each.

I would like to pull these sets back as comma delimited lists, which it seems group_concat is built for, but I keep ending up with a massive number of extra results, compounded with each additional join.  Although I think I have an idea why, I'm having difficulty visualizing how to architect the query to avoid this.

I've created a simplified version of what I'm trying to do in a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/862f30/4).  In case that link is ever unavailable, here is the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE users (ID INT, name VARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO users (ID, name)
VALUES (1, 'Jon');
INSERT INTO users (ID, name)
VALUES (2, 'Jane');

CREATE TABLE skills (ID INT, name VARCHAR(30), groupName VARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO skills (ID, name, groupName)
VALUES (1, 'Drawing', 'Art');
INSERT INTO skills (ID, name, groupName)
VALUES (2, '3D Animation', 'Art');
INSERT INTO skills (ID, name, groupName)
VALUES (3, 'javaScript', 'Programming');
INSERT INTO skills (ID, name, groupName)
VALUES (4, 'HTML', 'Programming');

CREATE TABLE users2skills (UID INT, SID INT);

INSERT INTO users2skills (UID, SID)
VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO users2skills (UID, SID)
VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO users2skills (UID, SID)
VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO users2skills (UID, SID)
VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO users2skills (UID, SID)
VALUES (2, 4);

CREATE TABLE shifts (ID INT, name VARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO shifts (ID, name)
VALUES (1, 'Daylight');
INSERT INTO shifts (ID, name)
VALUES (2, 'Evening');
INSERT INTO shifts (ID, name)
VALUES (3, 'Midnight');

CREATE TABLE users2shifts (UID INT, SID INT);
INSERT INTO users2shifts (UID, SID)
VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO users2shifts (UID, SID)
VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO users2shifts (UID, SID)
VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO users2shifts (UID, SID)
VALUES (2, 3);
```

To start, here is a simple query I put together which pulls the expected results:

```
select  u.ID,
        u.name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(skQ.ID order by skQ.ID) as skillList,
        GROUP_CONCAT(skQ.name order by skQ.ID) as skillDesc
        
from    users u
        left outer join (
                            select  u2sk.UID, sk.ID, sk.name
                            from    users2skills u2sk
                                    inner join skills sk    on sk.ID    = u2sk.SID
                            ) skQ on skQ.UID    = u.ID
group by u.ID,
        u.name
```

The results look like this:

```
ID name skillList skillDesc
1  Jon  3,4    javaScript,HTML
2  Jane 1,2,4  Drawing,3D Animation,HTML
```

Note that the order of both lists match, so I can programmatically join the IDs back up to the descriptions later.  However, I need additional data, including category descriptions for the skills, and want a final resultset that looks like this:

```
ID name skillList skillDesc      skillGroups             shiftList shiftDesc
1  Jon  3,4      javaScript,HTML Programming,Programming 1,2     Daylight,Evening
2 Jane 1,2,4    Drawing,3D Animation,HTML Art,Art,Programming 2,3 Evening,Midnight
```

So I added several new group_concat statements for the new table that I wish to join, creating this query:

```
select  u.ID,
        u.name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(skQ.ID order by skQ.ID) as skillList,
        GROUP_CONCAT(skQ.name order by skQ.ID) as skillDesc,
        GROUP_CONCAT(skQ.groupName order by skQ.ID) as skillGroups,
        GROUP_CONCAT(shQ.ID order by skQ.ID) as shiftList,
        GROUP_CONCAT(shQ.name order by skQ.ID) as shiftDesc
        
from    users u
        left outer join (
                            select  u2sk.UID, sk.ID, sk.name, sk.groupName
                            from    users2skills u2sk
                                    inner join skills sk    on sk.ID    = u2sk.SID
                            ) skQ on skQ.UID    = u.ID
        left outer join (
                            select  u2sh.UID, sh.ID, sh.name
                            from    users2shifts u2sh
                                    inner join shifts sh    on sh.ID    = u2sh.SID
                            ) shQ on shQ.UID    = u.ID
group by u.ID,
        u.name
```

However, the resultset returned by that is:

```
ID  name    skillList   skillDesc                                           skillGroups                                     shiftList       shiftDesc
1   Jon     3,3,4,4     javaScript,javaScript,HTML,HTML                     Programming,Programming,Programming,Programming     2,1,2,1     Evening,Daylight,Evening,Daylight
2   Jane    1,1,2,2,4,4 Drawing,Drawing,3D Animation,3D Animation,HTML,HTML Art,Art,Art,Art,Programming,Programming         3,2,3,2,3,2     Midnight,Evening,Midnight,Evening,Midnight,Evening
```

In my actual query this problem is multiplied, every list containing 100+ items.  I've seen a number of questions about how to resolve this, but those I've found general receive the same answer: use distinct.  This causes a problem for me because I have duplicate values in the "groupName" field, which distinct filters out.  This results in lists of different sizes, and prevents me from doing anything with the data after I get it back.

I would rather not need to make ten separate queries, with all of the associated overhead and connections between the web and DB servers, if I can help it.  I suspect a single query will be substantially faster anyway.  What is the proper way to get the data I need in the format I need it?

Comment: FWIW, I think issues of data display are best resolved in application code

Comment: @Strawberry I've begun to think along those lines myself.  But at this point, I'd really like to know the solution to this either way I decide to go, as I've sunk way too much time into it to not at least walk away with a lesson.

Comment: Well, perhaps that could be the lesson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple matches in both `left join`ed tables for a given row in the main table, so rows are being multiplied, and you end up with the same value being aggregated more than once.

Basically, you need to aggregate in subqueries:

```
select u.ID, u.name, skQ.skillList, skQ.skillDesc, sqQ.skillGroups, shQ.shiftList, shQ.shiftDesc
from users u
left outer join (
    select u2sk.UID, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(sk.ID        order by sk.ID) as skillList
        GROUP_CONCAT(sk.name      order by sk.ID) as skillDesc,
        GROUP_CONCAT(sk.groupName order by sk.ID) as skillGroups
    from users2skills u2sk
    inner join skills sk on sk.ID = u2sk.SID
    group by u2sk.uid
) skQ on skQ.UID  = u.ID
left outer join (
    select u2sh.UID, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(sh.ID   order by sh.ID) as shiftList,
        GROUP_CONCAT(sh.name order by sh.ID) as shiftDesc
    from users2shifts u2sh
    inner join shifts sh on sh.ID = u2sh.SID
) shQ on shQ.UID = u.ID
```

Comment: Thank you.  This makes perfect sense and works as expected.